# How to fix EConvertError handling in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

so i tried to make simple app to check if entered number is odd or even. Also i wanted to handle EConvertError by entering Try and Except.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  var x:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
try
  x:=StrToInt(InputBox('Zadávanie','Napíš číslo',''));
  if x mod 2 = 0 then ShowMessage('Zadané číslo je párne')
  else ShowMessage('Zadané číslo je nepárne');
except
on E: EConvertError do
    ShowMessage('Zadávaj len čísla!');
end;
end;
end.
```

But this don't work and still showing the same exact **Project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message ''' is not a vaild integer value** instead of 'Zadávaj len čísla!'. Why?

Comment: Because you're running the program under the debugger. Press continue and you'll see your message. Or run by ctrl+shift+f9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your `try..except` code is fine.

You are simply experiencing what happens when you run your app inside of the IDE's debugger. The debugger sees the exception before your app does. You are seeing a popup message from the debugger. Simply dismiss the popup and either press the "Run" button in the IDE, or press F9 on the keyboard, to continue execution and the exception will be passed to your app for normal handling, calling your `except` block.  The popup will not happen when you run your app outside of the debugger, the `except` will just be called immediately.

If you don't want the debugger to popup a message on the exception, you can add `EConvertError` to the debugger's  list of exceptions that it ignores. Or you can place breakpoints around the code that instruct the debugger to ignore exceptions for just this block of code.

Or, you can simply use `TryStrToInt()` instead of `StrToInt()`. `TryStrToInt()` does not raise an exception on a conversion error.

Comment: "...  Or you can place breakpoints around the code that instruct the debugger to ignore exceptions for just this block of code. ..."

How do you do that?

Comment: @KevinKillion place a breakpoint at the beginning of the code you want the debugger to ignore, then go into the [breakpoint's properties](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Breakpoint_Properties) and disable the "Break" option and enable the "Ignore subsequent exceptions" option. Then place another breakpoint at the end of the code to be ignored, go into its properties, and disable the "Break" option and enable the "Handle subsequent exceptions" option. Now, when you run the code, the debugger will ignore any exception that is raised by code executed in between the two breakpoints

Answer (score 3):

Just use `TryStrToInt()` which returns `false` if the input was no valid integer, something like that:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var x: integer;
begin
try
  if not TryStrToInt(InputBox('Zadávanie','Napíš číslo',''),x) then begin
    ShowMessage('Zadávaj len čísla!');
    exit;
  end;
  if x mod 2 = 0 then ShowMessage('Zadané číslo je párne')
  else ShowMessage('Zadané číslo je nepárne');
end;
```

So no exception will be raised on input error.

IMHO [exceptions should be exceptional](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2015/04/12/Why-Transmitting-Exceptions-in-SOA-services-is-not-a-good-idea) - I don't like using  `EConvertError` at all in my code.

BTW it is not a very good idea to put some UI code in the `OnCreate` event - better use `OnShow` for that.

Comment: But i wanted to show only the Inputbox so i was forced to do it OnCreate. And as soon as the form is created, close it

Comment: Your code won't close the form: `exit` in FormCreate will still display the form. You may call `halt` but it is a bit overkill, and may not be safe in some cases. The right way is to put the `InputBox` in the FormShow then call `Close` from there.